# Fancybox inline-content popup won't scroll?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Go to: http://blog.raceramps.com/resources/press-releases/
Click Track & Trailer Ramps

The popup won't let me scroll in it? Tried on various browsers. Only works on click/drag scroll bar, or intermittently.

http://fancybox.net/ inline popup works just fine - what am I missing?

Comment: Is it just that the mousewheel wont work or is the scroll bar missing too for you? (Tested Chrome 20.0-beta)

Comment: Seems to be the `<p>` tags that are causing this. Removed them and it works as expected.

Comment: @sg3s Mouse wheel for me. Scrolling by click-drag works and mouse wheel **on** the scrollbar works too.

Comment: Wow, what an unhelpful comment. There are multiple plugins that call jQuery more than once - one of them includes the mousewheel plugin. And yes, I did disable those to try to resolve the problem, and no dice. I hadn't dug into the plugins yet to disable multiple calls, but I did disable them to test.

Comment: For the record: I disagree with whom voted to close this question since I consider it can be helpful to others to learn how different versions of software/scripts can create different issues. I also disagree with @sg3s comment because the idea here is to help, no to criticize the lack of "common sense and debugging skills" of others (otherwise they wouldn't ask for help, would they?)

Comment: @JFK I was probably too harsh, so my apologies for that. The way the question is asked, leaving out things that could easily have been identified as important should have been included in the post. Jared says he DID test it without mousewheel plugin but didn't even mention it as a whole... Finally, some preliminary debugging should have been done to narrow down the problem so the relevant code could be posted here, at the moment everyone wanting to help is left with a page with a pile of javascript that isn't all that relevant.

Comment: He may not have posted any code but he provided a link ... which is better because firebug can show where the errors come from (I would rather deal with a live site than text code ... to lazy for that.) Anyways, in this case would be better to down vote the question (if you prefer) than to close it; my five cents.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery 1.7+ but your `mousewheel` plugin version is 3.0.4, which might be a little bit obsolete for jQuery 1.7+.

Try upgrading the `mousewheel` plugin to the latest version (3.0.6) from here https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/downloads

BTW, fancybox.net is still using jQuery v1.4.4 so this why it hasn't issues with the old `mousewheel` plugin.

Comment: I don't think it is the version of the mousewheel plugin, but more of a combination of events being blocked / overridden. I made this jsfiddle to test some stuff out with Fancybox2 (uses same mousewheel plugin) which is much better code, and should probably work better for the op, even in the state his website is in right now http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/XJHvq/30/